# Python Multithreading (while and apscheduler)

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to call two functions simultaneously in Python. One is an infinite loop and the other one is started using apscheduler. Like this:

**Thread.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import _While
import _Scheduler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=_While.main())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=_Scheduler.main())
    p2.start()
```

**_While.py**

```
import time


def main():
    while True:
        print "while"
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

**_Scheduler.py**

```
import logging
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler


def _scheduler():
        print "scheduler"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    scheduler = Scheduler(standalone=True)
    scheduler.add_interval_job(lambda:  _scheduler(), seconds=2)
    scheduler.start()
```

Since only while is printed it seems that _Scheduler isn’t starting.
Can somone help me?

Comment: It looks like you don't have a `_Scheduler.main` function...  Are you sure you're not seeing an `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got at least a couple problems here.  First, the `target` keyword should be a *function*, not the result of a function.  e.g.:

```
p1 = Process(target=_While.main)  # Note the lack of function call
```

Second, I don't see any `_Scheduler.main` function.  Maybe you meant to do something like:

```
import logging
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler


def _scheduler():
        print "scheduler"


def main():
    logging.basicConfig()
    scheduler = Scheduler(standalone=True)
    scheduler.add_interval_job(_scheduler, seconds=2)  # I doubt that `lambda` is necessary here ...
    scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```